# How to write a type guard function that tests against null or undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeguards, flow-js

In moving code from flow to js I have the following function:

```
export function nullOrUndefined(val: mixed): boolean %checks {
    return val === null || val === undefined;
}
```

Which can be moved to typescript quite easily (changing mixed to `unknown`)

However it is used like:

```
const mappedData: Map<string, string> = new Map([["key", "value"]]);
const value: undefined|string = mappedData.get("key"); 
//would be undefined if an invalid key is used
const sentence: string = "The key is: " + (nullOrUndefined(value) ? " not found" : value)
console.log(sentence);
```

When in flow the `%checks` makes sure the parser understand the function helps in type narrowing/guarding.
How would I do this in typescript?

EDIT: and yes I'm aware this can nearly always be done with the null coalescing operator, though this is from a codebase that is older than that operator.

Comment: Won't sentence always be a string? Why would JS want to know about type narrowing here? I might be wrong.

Comment: @TusharShahi you can't concatenate a string + `null` or `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use syntax like this to create a type guard:

```
export function nullOrUndefined(a: unknown): a is null | undefined {
  return a == null;
}
```

And, by the way, although `==` is normally discouraged over `===`, `==` with `null` is a great way to test for both `null` and `undefined` at the same time.

Comment: As much as it's true that you can use `==` here. It will likely require all devs that read the code to think twice and run a few tests to confirm this behavior

Comment: Just as a sidestep: but `any` should be `unknown` surely? As we only need "anything in, nothing out".

Comment: @JuanMendes The handy behaviour of testing if `something == null` to catch both `null` and `undefined` is something I use all over, under the assumption that it's idiomatic (as you point out, it probably isn't). I'm interested in how you'd express this.

Comment: @paul23, I like your suggestion of using `unknown` instead of `any`.

Comment: @JuanMendes, this usage of `==` is common enough that even the fairly strict ESLint rules for Standard JS make comparison to `null` an allowed exception to otherwise demanding `===`.